# When i set div size on auto, it goes down and overlaps the footer

Tags: html, footer

I have a container whose height is 2112px and I have a div box in it (width: 800px and height: 1200px), but when I set min-height to 1200px and height to auto ,then I overlaps my footer.

Is there way so that footer float to bottom as size increase?

Comment: try adding clear:both in footer div style

Answer (score 0):

Use the [clear](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear) property to avoid that:

```
footer {
    clear: both;
}
```